# Attempt to read property "name" on bool laravel 8, variable not transfering to view

Tags: php, laravel

I keep encountering this error on Laravel 8 with PHP 8. Im grabbing the id from the view like so:

```
  <button type="submit">
     <a href="{{route('employees.payslip', $employee->id)}}" class="text-green-600 hover:text-green-900">Payslip</a>
  </button>
```

This then goes to web.php like so:

```
Route::get('employees/{id}/payslip', ['App\Http\Controllers\PrintController', 'print'])->name('employees.payslip');
```

It then goes to the print function like so:

```
    public function print($id)
{
    $employees = Employees::findOrFail($id);
    $teams = Team::all();
    return view('employees.payslip',compact('employees', 'teams'));
}
```

When i remove the return view line and replace it with:

```
dd($employees);
```

It gives me the correct information but when i keep the line:

```
return view('employees.payslip',compact('employees', 'teams'));
```

and send it the view 'employees.payslip': it gives me the error: anyone has any ideas?

```
  @forelse($employees as $employee)
<tr>
  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
    {{$employee->name}}
  </td>
  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
    {{$employee->surname}}
  </td>
  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
    {{$employee->address}}
  </td>
  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
    {{$employee->phone}}
  </td>
  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
    {{$employee->role}}
  </td>
  <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap text-sm text-gray-500">
    {{$employee->absent}}
  </td>
</tr>
@empty
  <td>
    No Information to Display
  </td>
@endforelse
```

Comment: `$employees` is a single model, not a collection of Employees. You're currently trying to loop through the properties of a single Employee. Remove the loop and it should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are fetching one record from Employee model.So it return single object.

```
$employees = Employees::findOrFail($id);
```

so as @aynber said , you dont need loop.Its just like below to access data

```
  {{$employees->name}}
```

If you loop then error says

> Attempt to read property “name” on bool laravel 8, variable not
> transfering to view

```
 @forelse($employees as $employee)
@php 
dd($employee);
@endphp
@empty
  <td>
    No Information to Display
  </td>
@endforelse
```

here  `dd($employee);` will return `true` so it throwing erorr

Also keep in mind if no record then it might return null so make sure to chek like `isset` or `$employees->name??null`