# Barryvdh/laravel-domPDF returning Attempt to read property " " on bool

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, dompdf, laravel-dompdf

Im using Laravel 9.52.10 and PHP 8.0.28. i have CRUD that display preaching data can print it. that data only can printed per ID, not all of data preaching. but i have an error:

> Attempt to read property "judul_khotbah" on bool

this my route

```
Route::get('{id_khotbah}/khotbahPdf', [KhotbahController::class,'generatePdf'])->name('cetakPdf');
```

my controller

```
public function generatePdf(Request $request,$id_khotbah)
    {
        $khotbah = Khotbah::find($id_khotbah);

        $pdf = Pdf::loadView('dashboard.khotbahPdf' ,compact('khotbah'));
        return $pdf->download('RingkasanKhotbah.pdf');
    }
```

My blade

```
<body>
    @method('put')
    @csrf
    


        @foreach ($khotbah as $dataKhotbah)
            <div class="book">
                <div class="page">
                    <div class="subpage">
                        <h1>Judul Khotbah : {{ $dataKhotbah->judul_khotbah}}</h1>
                        <h5>Tanggal : {{ $dataKhotbah->tanggal_khotbah}}</h5>
                        <h5>Pembicara : {{ $dataKhotbah->pembicara}}</h5>
                        <br>
                        <p>{{ $dataKhotbah->isi_khotbah}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
</body>
```

and if add to my blade

```
@if (isset($khotbah) && count((array) $khotbah))
```

```
like this


<body>
    @method('put')
    @csrf
    @if (isset($khotbah) && count((array) $khotbah))


        @foreach ($khotbah as $dataKhotbah)
            <div class="book">
                <div class="page">
                    <div class="subpage">
                        <h1>Judul Khotbah : {{ $dataKhotbah->judul_khotbah ?? null }}</h1>
                        <h5>Tanggal : {{ $dataKhotbah->tanggal_khotbah ?? null }}</h5>
                        <h5>Pembicara : {{ $dataKhotbah->pembicara ?? null }}</h5>
                        <br>
                        <p>{{ $dataKhotbah->isi_khotbah ?? null }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</body>

it only print html without data
```

Comment: `Khotbah::find($id_khotbah);` returns a **single** `Khotbah` Model instance, or `null`.  `foreach()` on a single Model instance will loop it's public properties, like `property => true`, so `$dataKhotbah` on the first iteration is a boolean `true` (or `false`), and `true->judul_khotbah` is not valid PHP. Please read Laravel's documentation and learn the difference between `->find()`, `->first()`, `->get()`, etc., and how to work with a single Model instance vs a Collection or Array of Model instances.

Answer (score 0):

dont loop it, just delete your foreach, you are fetching one record.

```
            <div class="book">
                <div class="page">
                    <div class="subpage">
                        <h1>Judul Khotbah : {{ $khotbah->judul_khotbah }}</h1>
                        <h5>Tanggal : {{ $khotbah->tanggal_khotbah }}</h5>
                        <h5>Pembicara : {{ $khotbah->pembicara }}</h5>
                        <br>
                        <p>{{ $khotbah->isi_khotbah }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[Attempt to read property "name" on bool laravel 8, variable not transfering to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67837133/attempt-to-read-property-name-on-bool-laravel-8-variable-not-transfering-to-v)

thats the references

and i suggest you to do `::findOrFail` that will help you to abort the task if data is empty